# GA4 Item Name Duplicate Values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

Hi guys need your expert help. I have a client who sells membership. With each membership client also sell a supplementary membership (optional) which a user can purchase along with the primary. The problem is that in GA4, supplementary membership values are not showing up as unique. How can I fix this?

See attached screenshot

[image: 1]

I am expecting unique values for each membership.

Comment: Maybe you can share what code implementation you did here

Comment: it is just ecommerce purchase dataLayer.

Comment: I would say that is the total Supplementary membership purchased by all users